# Unable to scroll grid item with the background when using react-grid-layout

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, react-grid-layout

I am trying to create a screen which has a drag and drop edit grid.

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-dhawan-ywv9dy?file=/src/App.js

The issue i am facing is when i scroll vertically or horizontally the items in the grid are scrolling but the background is not scrolling with the items. I am not good in css so not able to figure out how to make sure the the grid items are aligned to the background grid when scrolling.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";

export default function App() {
  const [showGrid, setShowGrid] = useState(false);
  const layout = [
    { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2, static: false },
    { i: "b", x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2 },
    { i: "c", x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 }
  ];
  const toggleGrid = () => {
    setShowGrid(!showGrid);
  };
  return (
    <div
      className={`dashboard ${showGrid ? "editable" : ""}`}
      style={{
        overflow: "scroll"
      }}
    >
      <button onClick={toggleGrid}>Toggle Grid</button>
      {showGrid && (
        <GridLayout layout={layout} cols={26} rowHeight={160} width={4400}>
          <div style={{ border: "1px solid black" }} key="a">
            a
          </div>
          <div key="b" style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
            b
          </div>
          <div key="c" style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
            c
          </div>
        </GridLayout>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.dashboard {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.editable {
  background-color: rgba(218, 218, 218, 1);
  background-color: rgba(var(--palette-neutral-10, 218, 218, 218), 1);
  background-size: 170px 170px;
  background-position: 0 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 10px,
      rgba(232, 232, 232, 0) 10px,
      rgba(232, 232, 232, 0) 170px
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 10px,
      rgba(232, 232, 232, 0) 10px,
      rgba(232, 232, 232, 0) 170px
    );
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgba(var(--palette-neutral-0, 255, 255, 255), 1) 0,
      rgba(var(--palette-neutral-0, 255, 255, 255), 1) 10px,
      rgba(232, 232, 232, 0) 10px,
      rgba(232, 232, 232, 0) 170px
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      rgba(var(--palette-neutral-0, 255, 255, 255), 1) 0,
      rgba(var(--palette-neutral-0, 255, 255, 255), 1) 10px,
      rgba(232, 232, 232, 0) 10px,
      rgba(232, 232, 232, 0) 170px
    );
}
```

Can someone help with this?

The alignment and the grid need to hold up when zoomed in or zoomed out and the background grid need to cover the whole screen. The items need to align with the background grid and scroll with the grid